# DocuSign UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT Getting Error While all fields i made correct

Tags: docusignapi

I am using PHP as language using Raw API.
When Creating envelope i m posting following JSON Code.

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "compositeTemplateId": "b55d12e6-d82b-445c-910e-7e04a4480a82",
      "serverTemplates": [
        {
          "templateId": "b55d12e6-d82b-445c-910e-7e04a4480a82",
          "sequence": "1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "clientUserId": "1001",
        "email": "dev@gmail.com",
        "tabs": {
          "emailTabs": [
            {
              "anchorXOffset": "429",
              "anchorYOffset": "309",
              "value": "dev@gmail.com",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ],
          "textTabs": [
            {
              "anchorXOffset": "429",
              "anchorYOffset": "309",
              "name": "Job Title",
              "value": "JobTitleValue",
              "recipientId": "1"
            }
          ],
          "fullNameTabs": [
            {
              "anchorXOffset": "37",
              "anchorYOffset": "165",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "value": "Signer One"
            }
          ]
        },
        "name": "Signer One",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "roleName": "WebUser"
      }
    ]
  },
  "sender": {
    "accountId": "-------"
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

But when i m calling recipient view API i m getting this "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT" ERROR.
JSON data when calling API.

```
{
  "authenticationMethod": "email",
  "clientUserId": "1001",
  "email": "dev@gmail.com",
  "recipientId": "1",
  "returnUrl": "-----",
  "userName": "Signer One"
}
```

Also When i m calling get list on envelope recipient list

```
"signers": [
    {
      "creationReason": "sender",
      "canSignOffline": "true",
      "isBulkRecipient": "false",
      "recipientSuppliesTabs": "true",
      "requireUploadSignature": "false",
      "name": "Rakesh Jangid",
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "",
      "email": "rakesh@crystaltechesolutions.com",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "routingOrder": "1",
      "note": "",
      "roleName": "Owner",
      "status": "delivered",
      "completedCount": "0",
      "deliveredDateTime": "2021-06-23T09:22:23.3800000Z",
      "deliveryMethod": "email",
      "recipientType": "signer"
    }
  ],
  "agents": [],
  "editors": [],
  "intermediaries": [],
  "carbonCopies": [],
  "certifiedDeliveries": [],
  "inPersonSigners": [],
  "seals": [],
  "witnesses": [],
  "notaries": [],
  "recipientCount": "1",
  "currentRoutingOrder": "1"
}
```

can any one help me to get Receipent View links from API.

Answer (score 0):

```
"clientUserId": "1001"
```

This line has to also be on the recipient/signer, not just when requesting the recipient view.
So add this:

```
    "name": "Signer One",
    "recipientId": "1",
    "routingOrder": "1",
    "roleName": "WebUser",
    "clientUserId": "1001"
```

Comment: i have added in signers json.